# How to stop Electron from printing devtools extension errors to console?

Tags: vue.js, electron, devtools, vue-devtools

I've been using Vue devtools extension with Electron and whenever I activate and use Vue devtools, all the errors occurred from it gets printed out to the Electron's main process console like this.

[image]

It's so frustrating because It's hard to find any useful information printed out from my application in middle of these thousands of errors.

I know why the error occurs. It's because Vue devtools is trying to access the `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()` function which [isn't available on Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/extensions#chrometabs) but I don't really care about the errors occurring from Vue devtools here. I just need to stop Electron from printing these errors out. Looked through all of the devtools related documentation but found nothing on this.

Comment: It would help if you share a version of your packages and electron. I suspect this might be a problem.

Comment: Also, could you please share that part when you initialize the electron dev tools installer? There is a `catch`.

Comment: @vovchisko That `catch` block cannot catch these errors. It can catch errors thrown by Electron only when the extension is loaded (when `session.defaultSession.loadExtension()` is called by devtools installer). Also the issue persists with all versions of Electron and Vue dev tools. It's because Vue devtools is trying to access the `tabs.captureVisibleTab()` function which isn't available on Electron.